# How to send array of files and data to API server with FormData

Tags: asp.net-core, angular6

I hava a `fileUploader` component with `angular 6` and in the server side I use the `Asp.Net Core 2.0`.
Since the my files has larg size, I use the `FormData`.

I can send **a** file with data to server very well.
with this code:

**component:**

```
export class AttComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private attService: AttService) { }
    uploadFile()
    {
        var entity = {};
            entity.ID = 123;
            entity.ATT_ID = 456;
            entity.REFERENCE_TYPE = "referenceType";
            entity.REFRENCE_ID = "referenceID";

        this.attService.UploadFile(fileUploader.files[0], entity).subscribe((data: IServiceResult) =>
                {
                    console.log("fileUploader result => ", data);
                });
    }
}
```

**service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AttService
{
    UploadFile(file, entity: any): Observable<any> 
    {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            formData.append('att', JSON.stringify(entity));
            return this.http.Post("/UploadFile", formData);
    }
}
```

**Api Server:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(AttDTO model)
{
    //...
}
```

**DTO Class:**

```
public class AttDTO
    {
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
        public string att { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to send **array of file** with **data** to server with `FormData`. 
like this in `server`:

**server:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(List<AttDTO> obj)
{
    //...
}
```

**service**

```
uploadFile(lst: Array<any>): Observable<any>
    {
        var formData = new FormData();
        lst.forEach(item =>
        {
            formData.append('file', item.fILE);
            formData.append('att', JSON.stringify(item.att));
        });
        return this.http.Post("/UploadFile", formData);
    }
```

How do i do?

What's change in client side (component , service)?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have written the existing code then its simple, `fileUploader.files` as input for the method and then use forLoop to add files in the existing way

Comment: Is that `att` from DTO is always same for images?

Comment: no, `att` is different for each file

Comment: Try posted code and let me know if it works, otherwise will edit

Comment: *the formData is empty* how do you checking?

Comment: Sorry, the `lst` in `server Api` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after one day, I found the solution.

follow this:

**service:**

move `att` object to after loop and cast all of the lst to stringify.
like this:

```
uploadFile(lst: Array<any>): Observable<any>
    {
        var formData = new FormData();
        lst.forEach(item =>
        {
            formData.append('file', item.fILE);
        });
        formData.append('att', JSON.stringify(lst));
        return this.http.Post("/UploadFile", formData);
    }
```

**In server side**

I recieve data from `Request.Form` instead `parameter`.
like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
        {
            var att = Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString())["att"];
            var json = (JArray)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(att);

            List<AttDTO> lst = new List<AttDTO>();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in json.Children())
            {
                lst.Add(new AttDTO() { att = item.ToString(), file = Request.Form.Files[i] });
                ++i;
            }
            // ...
        }
```

I hope is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Component:

```
                           Send all files
                            \/\/\/\/\/\/
this.attService.UploadFile(fileUploader.files, entity).subscribe((data:IServiceResult) => {
    console.log("fileUploader result => ", data);
});
```

`UploadFile()` method in Service:

```
UploadFile(files, entity: any): Observable<any> {
 let data: any[] = []
  this.foods.forEach(file => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', item.fILE);
    formData.append('att', JSON.stringify(item.att));
    data.push(formData);
  });

 return this.http.Post("/UploadFile", data);
}
```

API Side change:

```
public class AttDTO
{
  public IFormFile file { get; set; }
  public string att { get; set; }
}
```

and method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IList<AttDTO> obj)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: thanks for attension, but `att` is different for each file

Comment: @A.R.F try the `let formData = new FormData();` inside for loop and outside forloop use `data : any[] = []` then add formData in local list and send that list to the API