# Error converting value "C:\fakepath\some_image.jpg" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile]'. Path 'photos'

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

While trying upload list of images as property of C# object above error is occurring.

I am trying to get image paths in c# object as parameter in my HttpPost method of ASP.Net Web API project

my C# object is

```
public class PostForCreateDto
{
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Body { get; set; }        
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<IFormFile> Photos { get; set; }

}
```

HttpPost method is

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PostForCreateDto postForCreateDto)
    {
       // do something from postForCreateDto
    }
```

before getting to this method error occurring **Error converting value "C:\fakepath\some_image.jpg" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile]'. Path 'photos'**

I tried with post method call like this using **[FomFrom]**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]PostForCreateDto postForCreateDto)
    {
       // do something from postForCreateDto
    }
```

then form is submitting without any errors but all fields in postForCreateDto are getting null values.

The page which is do posting(this is from angular)

```
<form [formGroup]="postForm" method="POST" (ngSubmit)="createPost()" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Title</h4>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Title" formControlName="title">      

<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Body</h4>
  <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Body" formControlName="body"> 
 </textarea>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <h4>Category</h4>
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Category" formControlName="category">      
</div>

<div class="form-group">     
  <h4>Photos</h4>
  <input type="file" multiple formControlName="photos">
</div>

<button typpe="submit" [disabled]="!postForm.valid" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
```

internally from angular method **createPost()** i am calling **Create([FromForm]PostForCreateDto postForCreateDto)** or **(Create(PostForCreateDto postForCreateDto))** method

createPost method

```
createPost() {
if (this.postForm.valid) {
  this.post = Object.assign({}, this.postForm.value);
  this.postService.createPost(this.post).subscribe(() => {
    this.alertify.success('post creation successful');
  }, (error: string) => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  }, () =>  {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
  });
}
```

}

I think the error coming from this line

**this.post = Object.assign({}, this.postForm.value);**

suggest me proper way calling post method with postCreateDto get some values in it.

Comment: how the Service Code looks like? API Call?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57024988/7124761

Comment: Plus this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537297/7124761 If you still finding difficulties then let me know! will post answer

Comment: Still i am not getting solution

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code

Comment: I have updated my question with API call from Angular. check it once

Comment: `console.log(this.postForm.value)?`

Comment: {title: "title", body: "body", category: "cat", …}
body:"body"
category:"cat"
photos:"C:\fakepath\some_image.jpg"
title:"title"
__proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}

Comment: "photos" got only one path even though i selected 2 files. Error coming from Path string of "photos"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198438/discussion-between-user3696047-and-prashant-pimpale).

Comment: I am unable help it for now will see in the morning..try hard until

Comment: you need to send that Image as in the form of `FormData`

Comment: Additionally share the code of `createPost` method

Comment: Just share the code of `createPost` will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Idea came from the comment given by  [Prashant Pimpale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7124761/prashant-pimpale) to use formdata

I changed angular createPost() as follows (formdata used)

```
createPost() {
if (this.postForm.valid) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('title', this.postForm.get('title').value);
  formData.append('body', this.postForm.get('body').value);      
  formData.append('categoryId', this.postForm.get('category').value);
  for (const photo of this.photos) {
    formData.append('photos', photo, photo.name);
  }      
  });
  this.postService.createPost(formData).subscribe(() => {
    this.alertify.success('post creation successful');
  }, (error: string) => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  }, () =>  {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
  });
}
```

}

and for photos input i added event listener and added photos property **(photos: File[ ] = [ ];)** to the component class

```
onFileSelect(event: any) {
if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
for (const file of event.target.files) {
  this.photos.push(file);
  }
 }
}
```

In my postService i added content headers as follows

```
createPost(data: any) {
 const headers = new HttpHeaders().append(
'Content-Disposition', 'multipart/form-data');
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post(urlForCreatePost, data, {headers});
}
```

Now this data is correctly binding to my PostForCreateDto.

This might be lengthy solution and this doesn't need send Json to web API Controller and Deserialize Json object in Controller class.

If anyone can do better solution with less code please suggest me. Less code is always better.

Note:  i write this solution so that this might helpful to others with the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: [Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net)
I suppose you can use dynamic objects too.